# Ubuntu 14.04 closed all programs and locked

Tags: 14.04, crash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. While running a program, Ubuntu automatically closed all my running programs and locked the system. How to fix that? Please help.

Edit: When I run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, I am shown this :

```
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9385.350407] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 13
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.061840] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.157134] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d57, idProduct=fa60
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.157141] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.157145] usb 2-1.1: Product: 2.4G Receiver
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.157148] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Compx
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.159494] input: Compx 2.4G Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:1D57:FA60.6A2D/input/input27191
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.214484] hid-generic 0003:1D57:FA60.6A2D: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Compx 2.4G Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.216149] input: Compx 2.4G Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:1D57:FA60.6A2E/input/input27192
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.216427] hid-generic 0003:1D57:FA60.6A2E: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Compx 2.4G Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input1
May 26 08:24:40 kanat kernel: [ 9386.218489] input: Compx 2.4G Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.2/0003:1D57:FA60.6A2F/input/input27193
May 26 08:24:41 kanat kernel: [ 9386.326299] hid-generic 0003:1D57:FA60.6A2F: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Compx 2.4G Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing might be due to memory hipe, hard disk bad sector or bios releated issues. Hence please check the system log and kernal logs to check what exactly the issue is and proceed based on it.

> tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
Note: gnome-system-log tool can be used if you are using gnome.
```

To check kernal messages - **dmesg**(/var/log/kern.log)

Comment: thanks for your response , but I still having previous error . I have just changed  my question , could you look please